# What C# regex expression can be used to strip out dots (.) in a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need a string with non alpha-numeric characters etc stripped out of it; I used the following:

```
wordsstr = Regex.Replace(wordsstr, "[^A-Za-z0-9,-_]", "");
```

The problem being dots (.)s are left in the string yet they are not specified to be kept. How could I make sure dots are gotten rid of too?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *are* specifying that they need to be kept - you're using `,-_` which is everything from U+002C to U+005F, including U+002E (period).

If you meant the `,-_` to *just* mean comma, dash and underscore you'll need to escape the dash, such as:

```
wordsstr = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^A-Za-z0-9,\-_]", "");
```

Alternatively, (as in Oded's comment) put the dash as the first or last character in the set, to prevent it being interpreted as a range specifier:

```
wordsstr = Regex.Replace(input, "[^A-Za-z0-9,_-]", "");
```

If that's not the aim, please be more specific: "non alpha-numeric characters etc" isn't really enough information to go on.

Comment: Instead of escaping the dash, if it is the first _or_ last character in the character class it will still be interpreted as a dash and not a character range specifier.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks, I'll add that as another option.

Comment: Thank you! This worked a treat. I'm still taming the regex monster.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
wordsstr = Regex.Replace(wordsstr, "[^-A-Za-z0-9,_]", "");
```

Your problem would be easier to understand if you write your expectation and actual result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 wordstr = Regex.Replace(wordstr, "[^A-Za-z0-9,\\-_]", "");
```

or better if you just want to have alpha-numerical characters:

```
wordstr = Regex.Replace(wordstr, "[^A-z0-9]", "");
```

The problem in your first regex is that the `-` char defines a range, so you have to escape it  to make it behave the way you want it to.